# How to collapse all rows in pandas dataframe across all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to collapse all the rows of a dataframe into one single row across all columns.

My data frame looks like the following:

| name | job | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | business | 100 |
| NAN | dentist | Nan |
| jack | Nan | Nan |

I am trying to get the following output:

| name | job | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob jack | business dentist | 100 |

I am trying to group across all columns, I do not care if the value column is converted to dtype `object` (string).

I'm just trying to collapse all the rows across all columns.

I've tried `groupby(index=0)` but did not get good results.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `join`:

```
out = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna().astype(str))).to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
       name               job  value
0  bob jack  business dentist  100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_df = df.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().astype(str).tolist()).str.join(' ').to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
       name               job  value
0  bob jack  business dentist  100.0
```